# OpenCV, dynamic modifying of webcam display

Tags: c++, opencv, grayscale, roi

Sorry if the title gave you the wrong idea, I tried to make it as brief as possible. In short, what I am trying to do is detect a face with Viola-Jones algorithm (already implemented), save it in a separate image, convert that image to grayscale, then slap the grayscale image back into its' original position, resulting in a webcam display with all faces (and any false positives, I suppose) colored gray and surrounded by a green rectangle. However, I get the following error message:

> Unhandled exception at 0x771115de in proba.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at >memory location 0x003ef2c8..

This is my code (the relevant part), any suggestion/advice would be appreciated:

```
face_cascade.detectMultiScale( frame_gray, faces, 1.1, 2, 0|CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30) );
for( int i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++ )
{
Point pt1(faces[i].x + faces[i].width, faces[i].y + faces[i].height);
Point pt2(faces[i].x, faces[i].y); 

Rect myROI(pt1, pt2);
Mat croppedImage;
Mat(frame, myROI).copyTo(croppedImage);
cvtColor(croppedImage, croppedImage, CV_BGR2GRAY ); //the last four lines process the image

croppedImage.copyTo(frame(Rect(pt1, croppedImage.size()))); //this should copy the image back into its' original location

rectangle(frame, pt1, pt2, cvScalar(0, 255, 0, 0), 1, 8, 0);  
}
//-- Show what you got
imshow( window_name, frame );
```

And sorry if I'm missing the obvious answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cropped grayscale image `croppedImage` is a 1 channel image but you are trying to overlay it onto 3 channel RGB image `frame`. In other words, the function `copyTo` in

```
croppedImage.copyTo(frame(Rect(pt1, croppedImage.size())));
```

expects `croppedImage` to have the same number of channels as `frame`. This is why you are getting the error.

**EDIT** To solve your issue you may try convert your grayscale cropped image back to RGB format (it will still look like the grayscale image). Something like

```
cvtColor(croppedImage, croppedImage, CV_BGR2GRAY );  // to grayscale
cvtColor(croppedImage, croppedImage, CV_GRAY2BGR );  // to RGB
croppedImage.copyTo(frame(Rect(pt1, croppedImage.size())));
```

Comment: I see, I suppose there's no way around it. The whole thing isn't crucial, I just wanted to test something out. Anyway, thank you for your time.